# Does the existence of the von Neumann hierarchy in models of Zermelo set theory with foundation imply that every set has ordinal rank?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

Let $T$ be the theory consisting of Zermelo's original set theoretic axioms (extensionality, empty set, pairing, union, powerset, infinity, separation, choice) together with foundation. Put more succinctly, $T$ consists of ${\rm ZFC}$ axioms without the replacement axiom scheme. The theory $T$ is too weak for most set theoretic purposes because, for instance, it cannot even prove the existence of transitive closures. We consider strengthening $T$ in the following two ways. Let $A$ be the axiom asserting that $V_\alpha$ exists for every $\alpha$ and let $A^*$ be the axiom asserting that every $x$ is an element of a $V_\alpha$. For example, $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of $T+A^*$. Does $T$ together with $A$ imply $A^*$? Or is it possible that $V_\alpha$ exists for every ordinal $\alpha$, but there is a set without an ordinal rank?

Comment: At first sight, the statement of $A$ appears depend on the existence of von Neumann ordinals, but I imagine you mean it to be taken as a assertion about recursions along arbitrarily long well-ordered sets?

Comment: Adam, I actually do mean for the statements $A$ and $A^*$ to depend on the existence of the von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: I see that now, since you allow $V_{\omega+\omega}$ as a model. So you require that any von Neumann ordinal be the spine of a stage of the cumulative hierarchy, but you allow the existence of well-ordered sets longer than any von Neumann ordinal.

I believe the answer is no. I will think a bit more and then try to justify this in an answer.

Comment: Yes, I also suspect that $A^*$ is stronger than $A$, but I have no idea how to construct a model of $T+A$ that does not satisfy $A^*$.

Comment: The model I would propose is something I came up with in connection with my own question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117910/can-one-exhibit-an-explicit-kuratowski-infinite-set-without-invoking-replacement for which I also believe the answer is no.

In a nutshell, take a model of finite set theory in which there is an infinite  descending chain $x_{n+1}\in x_n$. This is possible, even assuming Foundation. Then formally adjoin  $\omega$ levels of the cumulative hierarchy.

Comment: Granted, the model so obtained will not have  $\omega$  as an  element. For my own purposes  this was more or less the  point. Since you  want to have $\omega$, the construction has  to be modified. I think the general idea is sufficiently robust, but I'll have to make some claims I've not entirely checked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take the Zermelo ordinals to be defined by $Z(0) = 0$, $Z(\alpha+1) = \{Z(\alpha)\}$, and $Z(\lambda) = \{Z(\alpha): \alpha<\lambda\}$ (where $\alpha, \lambda$ are von Neumann ordinals). Then if we add $Z(\omega+ \omega)$ to $V_{\omega +\omega}$ and close under pairing, union, subsets, and powersets, we get a model of $T$ - Choice + $A$ which is not a model of $A^*$.

More precisely, let $D_0 = V_{\omega+\omega} \cup\{Z(\omega+\omega)\}$ and $D_{n+1}$ be the result of adding pairs, unions, subsets, and powersets of element of $D_n$ to $D_n$. Clearly, $M = \bigcup_{n <\omega}D_n$ is transitive and models $T$ - Choice. A simple induction shows that:

For every $x\in D_n$ there is an $\alpha<\omega+\omega$ such that the (von Neumann) ordinals in $tc(x)$ are less than $\alpha$.

Since $V_{\omega+\omega}\subseteq M$, it follows that the von Neumann ordinals in $M$ are just those in $\omega+\omega$. So it models $A$. Since the rank of $Z(\omega+\omega)$ is $\omega+\omega$, it doesn't model $A^*$.

(To get Choice in the form ``every set is well-orderable" we just throw in $x \times x$ at $D_{n+1}$ for $x\in D_n$).

Comment: Very nice - and transitive too.

Answer (score 4):

If i understand you correctly, your A* is equivalent to the assertion that every set x belongs to a transitive set X s.t. every subset of a member of X is a member of X. (That way you don't have to talk about Von neumann ordinals - or any ordinals at all).  I'd bet very good money that this is not a theorem of Zermelo, and [slightly less money] that you will find this fact proved in a recent JSL article by A.R.D.Mathias under the title ``thin models of set theory''.

Comment: Weclome back to MathOverflow! Would you consider registering your account so we can properly recombine [your](http://mathoverflow.net/users/33663/thomas-forster) [multiple](http://mathoverflow.net/users/38445/thomas-forster) [personas](http://mathoverflow.net/users/39425/thomas-forster). Contact <moderators@mathoverflow.net> for assistance.

Comment: Dear Thomas, You are most welcome. I am one of the fans of non well founded set theory, specially your beauty book "Set theory with a universal set".

Answer (score 3):

As a partial answer: It follows at least from recursion and replacement over $\omega$:

Assume $\lnot A^\star$, then there exists a set $x$ such that $\not\exists_{\alpha\in\operatorname{On}} x\in V_\alpha$. Especially, therefore, we can find a set $y\in x$ such that also $\not\exists_{\alpha\in\operatorname{On}} y\in V_\alpha$, especially, $y\neq\emptyset$. Recursively, we can therefore define a sequence $x=x_0\ni y=x_1\ni x_2\ni x_2\ni \ldots$, and this contradicts the foundation axiom.

On the other hand, from $A^\star$ should follow that every set is well-founded, and therefore at least $\omega$-Induction, which should imply $\omega$-Induction and $\omega$-Replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Assertion $A^*$ is strictly stronger than  assertion $A$.

Denote  by $Z$ the theory with axioms Extensionality, Empty Set, Pairing, Union, Power Set, Infinity, Separation Schema, Foundation. Adding Choice is yields a theory which is essentially your $T$ but for an important fine point, namely, the precise formulation of the  Axiom of Infinity.  My own preference is for the Axiom of Infinity to be the assertion  of the existence of  a  Kuratowski infinite set. This assertion  is provably weaker than  both Zermelo's original formulation and the customary formulation in terms of inductive sets (see *Slim Models of Zermelo  Set Theory* by Mathias).

Let $F$ be the theory obtained from $Z$ by replacing my preferred Axiom of Infinity by its negation. In this theory, Replacement is a theorem schema and Choice is a theorem: thus, $F$ is a reformulation of the finite theory of Enayat-Schmerl-Visser's article *$\omega$-models of finite set theory*.

Let  ${\bf M}=(X,\lhd)$ be an $\omega$-model  of $F+ \exists \phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is the assertion "every element of the transitive closure of {$x$} is a singleton". Note  that membership in this transitive closure is expressible by a first-order formula. There is no requirement  that this transitive closure exist as  a  set: indeed it cannot, since  $\bf M\models$ Foundation. There  are  various ways to obtain such a model. One method is to apply the Rieger-Bernays permutation procedure to the standard  model $(V_\omega\in)$ and a cleverly chosen  permutation $\sigma:V_\omega\rightarrow V_\omega$ to obtain ${\bf  M}=(V_\omega,\in_\sigma)$ where $x \in_\sigma y\Leftrightarrow  x\in  \sigma(y)$: see Section 3 of  *A note  on recursive models of set theory* by Mancini-Zambella. Another is  to construct $\bf M$  directly by starting with a linear order $\ldots  < x_{n+1}< x_n\ldots< x_0$ and iterating $\omega$  many  times the procedure of formally  adjoining  power sets of finite subsets (taking care to *e.g.* identify {$x_{n+1}$} with $x_n$). For details, see the paper of Enayat-Schmerl-Visser.

In work  in progress addressed at my own Math Overflow  question [Can one exhibit an explicit Kuratowski infinite set without invoking Replacement?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117910/can-one-exhibit-an-explicit-kuratowski-infinite-set-without-invoking-replacement) I've  been adapting  this idea of formally adjoining power  sets to the setting where one is  given an $\omega$-model of $F$ and an  appropriate  collection of (external) infinite subsets of its underlying set, and where one wishes to produce a suitably minimal $\omega$-model of $Z$ whose "hereditarily finite" sets are  those of the original  model, and which has members with the specified infinite extensions. Given ${\bf M}=(X,\lhd)$ as in the previous paragraph, for every $x$ such  that $\phi(x)$ we formally adjoin an element with extension {$x$,{$x$},{{$x$}},$\ldots$},  then formally adjoin any missing elements with finite extension in this  augmented domain (taking due care as alluded to previously) and iterate $\omega$-many times. The resulting structure $\widehat{\bf M}$ will be a model of  $Z$  (including the Axiom of Infinity) with  the property that the class $V_\omega$ has no infinite subset.

For reasons of symmetry, $\widehat{\bf M}$ has no definable infinite sets. While this responds to the question  I originally posed, the fact that Transitive Containment is  violated feels a  bit like cheating. I have another construction for that, but I am digressing  far too much already.

My proposal would be to modify the recipe by also formally adjoining an  element with extension $V_\omega$ at the first stage, then  proceeding as  indicated above, *i.e.* lather,  rinse and repeat $\omega$ many times.